# Inputing images into an array in Javascript and then displaying them in a table

Tags: javascript, image

In this block of code I am loading some images of dice, and trying to display a few of those in the table.  I am not sure if I am even building the array right, but this was one of the examples I found of propagating an array with images.

```
<table id="dicebox">
                <tr>
                    <td id="d1"></td>
                    <td id="d2"></td>
                    <td id="d3"></td>
                    <td id="d4"></td>
                    <td id="d5"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<script>

            var diceB = new Array(7);
            //Blue dice
            var diceP = new Array(7);
            //Purple dice
            var diceValue = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

            //initializing blue dice array
            diceB[0] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[0].src = "images/dice0B.gif"
            diceB[1] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[1].src = "images/dice1B.gif"
            diceB[2] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[2].src = "images/dice2B.gif"
            diceB[3] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[3].src = "images/dice3B.gif"
            diceB[4] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[4].src = "images/dice4B.gif"
            diceB[5] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[5].src = "images/dice5B.gif"
            diceB[6] = new Image(50, 50);
            diceB[6].src = "images/dice6B.gif"


            for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = diceB[i].src;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dice"?

Comment: The things you roll in games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

```
for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    document.getElementById('d' + i).appendChild(diceB[i]);
```

Comment: Can you append an Image object directly or do you need to create an image tag?

Comment: @LeviBotelho Image tags is used in html mark up, image object is used in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You did not write an image tag, you have to do the following:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = '<img src="'+diceB[i].src+'" />';

}
```